# Two-dimensional array with categories?

Tags: python

I need to create a program - with the most basic Python coding possible. 
First, a text file must be read in that is just a list of names. I've already done this part.
For each name in the text file, it has to be given 4 "categories" (for this question's sake, Category A, Category B etc) Each category for each name must be given a value of between 1 and 10, which has to be randomly generated. I imagine this would be done with a two-dimensional array.

I know only very basic Python so I wouldn't know how to code this, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you show us your code and the point you got stuck using a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Can you use dictionaries for this problem, if we stored such like `{'name' : 'something', 'cat_1':  3', 'cat_2': 4, 'cat_3': 10, 'cat_4': 6}` ?

Comment: Or a list with dictionaries `Names = [{name1}, {name2}, {name3}]` or are we adding the categories with their numbers to the end of the name in the text file?

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

> First, a text file must be read in that is just a list of names.

```
import random
result = []

with open('file.txt') as f:
    names = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

> For each name in the text file,

```
for name in names:
```

> it has to be given 4 "categories" (...) Each category for each name must be given a value of between 1 and 10, which has to be randomly generated

```
    d = {'Category {}'.format(cat): random.randint(1, 10) for cat in 'ABCD'}
    d['name'] = name
    result.append(d)

print(result)
```